# How to see if a php session is set?

Tags: php, session

Ok this timed session thing is new to me I have created some test code. Here is the form that post the start of the session:

```
<?php
echo '<form action="index2.php?content=merc_script" method="post">';
echo '<input type="radio" name="Archer" value="1"">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Hire Archer">';
echo '</form>';
?>
```

and here is the test code:

```
if(isset($_POST['Archer'])){
$archer = ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","3600");
echo "Your Cookie is set!";
echo "$archer";
exit();
}


else{
echo "The Cookie was NOT set";
}
```

This code generates the session or so it says: 
Your Cookie is set!0
Here is the code I am using it in which is a fighting script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["Archer"])){
echo "The Archer is with you";
exit;
}
else{
echo "You have no Mercenary to help You!";
}
?>
```

When I go to fight a monster it says:
You have no Mercenary to help You!
Can someone please explain how to do this properly?

## Thanks in advance

I have edited this post because I am getting confused. I have a global session_start(); in a header file which is included in  every script I call. I have tried every suggestion and still can't seem to find the answer sorry for upsetting anyone if I did I am just trying to find a solution.

Comment: first make sure you started the session

Comment: and the added quote here `value="1""` <<< could have adverse effects

Comment: You have no session code at all. Check out [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I have tried all of your suggestions I took the extra quote hash out and added print_r $_SESSION and my session_start(); is in my header file which is global so I tried to set it on the fight script and said session already started I am stumped been searching high and low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session Start requires parentheses otherwise php mistakes it for a constant.

```
session_start();
$key = 'my_key';
// check to see if session variable is set
if(isset($_SESSION[$key])){
    $val = $_SESSION[$key];
    echo "Key is set. The value is: $val"; 
}else{
    // not set, setting a session variable at a specific key
    $_SESSION[$key] = 'Some Value';
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it came back with just a 0 so does that mean its set to value 0 or mean its NULL?

Comment: @TerryJ. look at my code. Look at yours. You are setting the ini cookie lifetime. This just indicates how long you want it to last. (Which I'm not even sure is correct but I am unwilling to look into further) Nowhere are you setting a Session variable.  Look at my else clause above. This is how you set it, AFTER you have called session_start()

Comment: your code works it sets the value to Archert from the posted form thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to set a time limit on it.

Answer (score 0):

One word of advice, of you are doing any session type of stuff (in fact just do this always), make the first statement in you file `session_start;` ie:

```
<?php
    session_start;
    // other stuff here
?>
```

This starts a session if one doesn't exist yet, and if one exists it uses the existing session.

Comment: I tried that, it said session had already been started, I am using a global session_start(); in my header file .

Comment: You cannot use the session_start function more than once in a file. It usually get the "session had already been started" error if you place that statement more than once in a file. This also applies if you include a php file that already includes a session_start statement.